# Need help creating class to return names in reverse and return initials

Tags: java

For homework, I need to write a class Name that has two constructors, one with 3 arguments for first, last, and middle initial, and one with two arguments for just first and last. I have to make the methods getNormalOrder, getReverseOrder, and getInitials. So if the name was John W Smith, getReverseOrder would return Smith, John W., getInitials would return JWS, and getNormalOrder would return it regularly. I keep getting the error:

```
method getInitials in class Name cannot be applied to given types;
```

when I test the method in another file. I'll put my code below.

```
class Name {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private char middleName;

  public Name(String firstName, char middleName, String lastName) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getReverseOrder(String first, char middle, String last) {
    String a = "";
    a += last;
    a += ", ";
    a += first;
    a += " ";
    a += middle;

    return a;
}

     public String getReverseOrder(String first, String last) {
    String a = "";
    a += last;
    a += ", ";
    a += first;

    return a;
}

public String getInitials(String first, char middle, String last) {
    String a = "";
     a += first.charAt(0);
     a += middle;
     a += last.charAt(0);
    return a;
}

   public String getInitials(String first, String last) {
    String a = "";
     a += first.charAt(0);
     a += last.charAt(0);
    return a;
  }

}
```

I haven't written getNormalOrder yet. This is how I'm testing it right now. I think I did everything completely wrong.

```
public class NameTest {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    Name teacher = new Name("John", 'W', "Smith");
    Name tf = new Name("John", "Smith");

    System.out.println(teacher.getInitials());
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you call the method with no arguments

```
teacher.getInitials()
```

But the methods defined in your class take 2 and 3 arguments, respectively

```
getInitials(String first, String last)
getInitials(String first, char middle, String last)
```

You don't need any arguments for these methods as the necessary data (first, middle, last) is already stored in a class member. The method should use these. The same is true for the other methods.

As an example for `getInitials()` (with only first and last name)

```
public String getInitials() {
    String a = "";
     a += firstName.charAt(0);
     a += lastName.charAt(0);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getInitials method shouldn't require any arguments. It should return a value using class members. You can use this.first to distinguish class members and local variables.